# REF(A + B) = REF(A) + REF(B) [Strang P130 3.3.5]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Describe all $m$ by $n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $ref(A) + ref(B) = ref(A + B)$.
>   Is it true that $ref(A) = A$ and $ref(B) = B$? Does $ref(A - B) = rref(A - B)$?
>   Here, ref = Row Echelon Form, rref = Reduced Row Echelon Form.
>
> **Terse Answer:** I think $ref(A) = A$ and $ref(B) = B$ are true.
>   But $REF(A) - REF(B)$ may have $-1$ in some pivots.

Would someone please explain and uncloak how to start, still less solve, this question?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is Strang's question?

I mean, the row echelon form is hardly unique. For instance, with $1\times 1$ matrices, all of the following are in row echelon form and, except for $(0)$, they are all equivalent:

$$
(1) \ , \ (0) \ , (\pi ) \ , \ (e) \ , (10^4) \dots
$$

So, I cannot see how any identity between **unreduced** row echelon forms can (cannot?) be true or tell anything about the matrices involved in it.

The **reduced** row echelon form is something completely different, since it's unique; that is, every matrix has a unique reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strang`s question is for $2 \times 3$ matrices but I thought to generalise it. The rest is the same.